# Is this the right way to construct the adjunction space homotopy equivalent to $S^1$? If not, then how to do it?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Currently, I'm working on an example from a topology book which states that **The sphere $S^n$ can be obtained by attaching an $n$-cell to a space with one point: $D^n\cup_f\{a\}$**.

> **Question:**
>
> I want to start with $Y=S_1\cup S_2$ s.t. $S_1,S_2\cong S^1$ (i.e. $S_1,S_2$ are homeomorphic with $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2+y^2=1\}$) and $S^1\cap S^2=\{p\}$. Then I want to construct a space $Y\cup_f D^2$ **homotopy equivalent** to $S^1$.

Choose a subset $K\subset Y$ and from that, define a continuous map and use the equivalence relation generated by that relation to glue the two spaces together.

How do I choose that $K$? And which $f$ should be used to define the equivalence relation?

(I choose $S^1$ to be the goal because it is a relatively simple situation for this problem.)

---

**My Attempt:**

First I have $S_1,S_2\cong S^1$ (i.e. $S_1,S_2$ are homeomorphic with $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2+y^2=1\}$) and $S^1\cap S^2=\{p\}$. I denote this space $Y=S_1\cup S_2$, and then I need to construct $Y\cup_f D^2\simeq S^1$.

I tried different kind of closed subset $K$ of $Y$:

> 1. $K$ containing both part of $S_1$ and $S_2$ s.t. $K\cap S_1\supseteq\{p\}$ and $f:K\to \partial D^2$ to be a continuous mapping such that $f(K)$ is an arc on $\partial D^2$, I tried to identify those point by the equivalence relation $\sim$ generated by $ k\sim f(k),\forall k\in K$. And the graph is like the picture below and is obviously not homotopic equivalent to $S^1$.
>    [image]

---

> 2. Select $K=S_2$ and then the *Urysohn Lemma* ensures that $\exists f:K\to\partial D^2$ which is a continuous mapping to an arc of $D^2$, to be specific, donote that arc to be $A$ and $f$ maps $K$ onto the arc $A$. Then, I got the following diagram by the universal property of the adjunction space. Identify the equivalence class $\simeq$ generated by $k\simeq f(k)\simeq f^{-1}(\{f(k)\})$
>
> [image]
>
> The resulting space is a small circle ($S_1$) and $D^2$. Define a retraction on $Y\cup_\phi D^2 $, so that we can retract $D^2$ to the connecting point $p$, which means $Y\cup_\phi D^2\simeq S^1$. But this seems invalid. since there are two layers by the disjoint union, then I don't know how to visualize the result because it seems to be a very strange space......

**My Problem:**

I'm not sure if this construction is valid, because $Y$ and $D^2$ are both subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I wonder in this case

*1) How to choose the right $K\subset Y$?*

*2) How to visualize and test if the resulting space is what I've been looking for?*

Note: I'm pretty sure that there exists such $K$ since there is an exercise question asking for this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time and effort!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You say you want a cell decmposition of $S^1$, but you start already with two copies of $S^1$... And moreover you are glueing a disk $D^2$. If you remove two points from the interior of $D^2$, it stays connected, whereas if you remove two points in $S^1$ it gets disconnected, so there is no chance that glueing a $D^2$ will give you something homeomorphic to a $S^1$. You can surely get something homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, but again you started with a space more complicated than $S^1$

Comment: Your title question, and the first question in your text, are pretty much impossible to address. There are many, many, many, many different ways to construct spaces homeomorphic to, or homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, and there is no hope of describing all such constructions. And you are right about construction 1, it fails.

Comment: Regarding construction 2, are you simply asking whether the construction succeeds at producing a space homotopy equivalent to $S^1$? If so, the question is still unclear, because you have not specified how the map $f : K \to D^2$ is defined. You don't need the Urysohn Lemma to deduce the existence a continuous function from $K=S_2$ to $\partial D_2$, there are many, many, many, many such functions that you can construct without any trouble. But you must be more specific about the properties of the map $f$ before anything can be said. Is $f$ a constant map? Is it a homeomorphism? .....

Comment: @LeeMosher OK, I specified the details of $f$ to be onto an arc which is a part of  $\partial D^2$, I think I have shown the image of $f$ in the picture of construction No.2.

Comment: I'm afraid that my second construction fails since the disjoint union contains two layers, and I don't know what the resulting space looks like, is it homotopy equivalent to the unit circle?

Comment: @ThibautBenjamin Hi, you said that I can get something homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, but how to choose that subset? Could you please briefly explain that process starting with the space I used in the post? (I have already edited it so it may be clearer than before) :O

Comment: I had in mind what Captain Lama explain, where you fill up one of the two $S^1$ by a $D^2$, making this part contractible and thus making the total space homotopy equivalent to a $S^1$, but not in a very interesting way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second construction is indeed valid.

There is a convenient term for your space $Y$, it is called the "wedge product" of two copies of $S^1$, denoted by $S^1 \vee S^1$. In general, for two pointed spaces $(A,a_0), (B,b_0)$ we define the wedge product as

$$ A\vee B = A\sqcup B /\{a_0, b_0\}. $$
That is, take their disjoint union, and attach them together at their basepoints, which for us is some arbitrary $p\in S^1$. A very nice property of this construction is that if $B$ is contractible then $A\vee B$ is homotopy equivalent to $A$ (proof: exercise).

Now for your space $Y = S^1 \vee S^1$, if you choose $K$ to be the subset $\{p \} \vee S^1$ and attach a disc $D^2$ to $K$ by mapping its boundary identically onto the second copy of $S^1$ the resulting space is $$Y' = Y \cup_{id_2} D^2 \cong S^1 \vee D^2 \simeq S^1$$

(where the basepoint of $D^2$ is also $p$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Um..And, I saw in the definition of adjunction space that $$A\cup_f B=(A\sqcup B)/\sim$$, we should identify the equivalence class but the disjoint union reflects that the resulting space has two layers. it becomes a paradox I think. So I wonder if I have misunderstood the definition.

Comment: It's possible you may be misunderstanding something, but I don't know what is the idea you mean to describe by "layers". To form the adjunction space we start with the disjoint union $A\sqcup B$, but then glue together parts of $A$ and $B$ according to $f$. If you're thinking about $A$ and $B$ as your two "layers" then in effect we're gluing parts of these "layers" together to form the adjunction space, i.e. there is a quotient map $A\sqcup B \to A\cup_f B$. There is no paradox.

Comment: The definition I have in mind for adjunction space is that there is some subset $C\subset B$ and a continuous function $f\colon C \to A$, and we define the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $A\sqcup B$ to be generated by $c \sim f(c)$ for all $c \in C$. Then the adjunction space is just the quotient that you wrote down.

Comment: OK, what I mean by "layers" is that when we take the disjoint union, we don't put the intersection together, instead, we add index to each the intersecting point, so it forms two layers, is that right?

Comment: OK, then I understand, thank you very much. I will read your proof in more details, I think it's good.

Comment: Yeah, if we want to form the disjoint union and it's possible that $A\cap B \neq\emptyset$ then we need to "disjointify" $A$ and $B$, and one way of doing that is to replace them with $A\times\{0\}$ and $B\times \{1\}$. Then when we form the adjunction space it's really $(A\times \{0\} \cup B \times \{1\})/\sim$ but there are still canonical functions $A \to A\cup_f B$ and $C\subset B \to A\cup_f B$. If $f$ is injective then these are both embeddings, so we can pretend like $A$ and $B$ are subspaces whose intersection is $C$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you are trying to do with the Urysohn lemma, but it seems to me that the method is very simple.

Choose one of your two circles, say $S_2$. Since it is a circle, it is homeomorphic to the border of a disk $D^2$. Just glue the disk on the circle. It makes the $S_2$ part of $Y$ contractible, so the resulting space is homotopy equivalent to $S_1=S^1$.

Comment: Just ignore the part of the Urysohn Lemma, it is not necessary for this question. Um... So your proof actually gives a afformative answer for my second construction, right? But since the adjunction space needs to be the disjoint union of two spaces under a quotient map, the resulting space should be two layers and from that, it forms a strange shape so is it homotopy equivalent to $S^1$?

Comment: I don't know what an adjunction space is, and I don't understand what these "layers" are, but the construction is much simpler than you seem to think. Take some wire, make two loops, and glue them at one point. This is $Y$. Now take a disk of plastic film, and glue this disk along one of the two circles, making a sort of dome. This this the final space. The dome part is contractible, so up to homotopy equivalence it just remains a circle.